# Best way to call tippy() after new elements are loaded to the DOM through Livewire/Alpine.js

Tags: laravel-livewire, alpine.js

I am currently calling tippy on x-init in my body tag to get tippy initiated the first time:

```html
<body x-data x-init="tippy('[data-tippy-content]')">
```

When Livewire adds/removes elements to the DOM, I need to call tippy() again to catch any new tags.

As per Livewire docs, I can hook into new elements being initalised like so:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
    Livewire.hook('component.initialized', (component) => {})
    Livewire.hook('element.initialized', (el, component) => {
        el.dispatchEvent(new Event("livewire-element-initialized"));
    })
    Livewire.hook('element.updating', (fromEl, toEl, component) => {})
    Livewire.hook('element.updated', (el, component) => {})
    Livewire.hook('element.removed', (el, component) => {})
    Livewire.hook('message.sent', (message, component) => {})
    Livewire.hook('message.failed', (message, component) => {})
    Livewire.hook('message.received', (message, component) => {})
    Livewire.hook('message.processed', (message, component) => {})
});
```

And then add a listener to my body tag like so:

```html
<body x-data x-on:livewire-element-initialized.window="tippy('[data-tippy-content]')">
```

While this works, I fear it is sub-optimal, and there are better ways. This event fires many times on every operation. I only need tippy() to be called once per DOM update.

Comment: While this doesn't answer the question directly, I'd advise to go with the [alpine component](https://alpinejs.dev/component/tooltip) route. Works fine for me.

Comment: @edvordo that's perfect advice for my application. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For my use case, this is perfect:

https://alpinejs.dev/component/tooltip